# How would I reference a double value without making a new object?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, double, encapsulation

The problem I have is that I want to make a generic code block of code. The getHalfDotTime method and getHalfTime method are two of many many similar methods.

I do not want to create a new ActionListener for every single method and instead I want to create the ActionListener within the commonFormatting method.

The problem I am running into when I do this is that the Declarations.halfDotTime double variable can not be contained as a local double for example.

I wanted double currentTitle = Declarations.halfDotTime and then in the ActionListener setText to currentTitle. This problem created was that as the program runs through it sets current title to the INIT value of 0 and then stays as 0 when the button is pressed.

```
private static void gethalfDotTime(JButton tapButton, JPanel contentPane) {
        final JLabel currentLabel = new JLabel("0ms");
        currentLabel.setBounds(119, 185, 120, 16);

    tapButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            currentLabel.setText(Declarations.threeDecimals.format(Declarations.halfDotTime) + "ms");
        }
    }); 
        commonFormatting(tapButton, contentPane, currentLabel);
    }

private static void gethalfTime(JButton tapButton, JPanel contentPane) {
        final JLabel currentLabel = new JLabel("0ms");
        currentLabel.setBounds(119, 185, 120, 16);

    tapButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            currentLabel.setText(Declarations.threeDecimals.format(Declarations.halfTime) + "ms");
        }
    }); 
        commonFormatting(contentPane, currentLabel);
    }

//MANY MORE SIMILAR METHODS ALL CALLING COMMON FORMATTING.



private static void commonFormatting(JPanel contentPane, final JLabel currentLabel) {

    currentLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    currentLabel.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    currentLabel.setFont(new Font("Letter Gothic Std", Font.BOLD, 14));
    contentPane.add(currentLabel);
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing code and should therefore be asked on [codereview.se]

Comment: It's not a review it's a problem. I have solved it now though and will post the solution if it get's unlocked. I have also reworded the question as it was a total mess! My apologies to all!

Comment: Sure, after your edit it looks better. Before it really seemed like you wanted to improve your code style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `commonTitle` as a new extra method parameter to `commonFormatting`. Your `commonTitle` variables are local variables, which means they are only visible inside the method they are declared in.

Polymorphism and encapsulation have nothing to do with why the code does not compile. Indeed, you are not using polymorphism, which might be a good way to solve this problem.

Comment: I did this. This code isn't a direct copy I kind of rebuilt it in stackoverflow. That didnt work the problem is that if I don't make a new action listener for every method. The value won't update when clicked as the value is being called before commonFormatting. And the remains a static value of 0

Comment: OK, you made me angry and I am going to vote to close this question. So many things wrong here: your comment does not give enough detail, you didn't provide real code but wasted my time with fake code, you don't seem to know what you are talking about.

Comment: OK Robin, I apologise for making you angry. This code had my head in a mess. You actually have helped me so I am going to mark you as right. Sorry my questions was all over the place. I needed to implement polymorphism. I now have a public field in a separate class called currentTitle and instead of calling from the ActionListener Declarations.halfDotTime I actually from the class that sets the value call this HalfDotTime.currentTitle = ((60000/timeValue)*3); (naming the class helps me keep it organised whilst having about 30 currentTitles) if the message gets unlocked I will post my solution!